# I want to return new column using Recursive in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table with column shown below

```
| Employee ID | Manager ID |
|:-----------:|:----------:|
| E068        | E067       |
| E071        | E067       |
| E229        | E069       |
| E248        | E144       |
| E226        | E223       |
| E236        | E241       |
| E066        | E001       |
| E067        | E001       |
| E144        | E001       |
| E223        | E001       |
| E001        | Null       |
| E241        | Null       |
```

And we do have table which contains 'Leader ID'

```
| Leader ID |
|-----------|
| E001      |
| E241      |
```

Problem Statement:

This problem is to identify the Head of Manager by using Employee and their Manager data.

About: We have an Employee ID and their Manager ID. Please note that Manager ID are from Employee ID. Since each manager has one Manager above their level.

First, we'll take all UNIQUE ID in Manager ID column.
Then for each ID from Manager ID column, we will look for their respective Manager ID(Manager)
Then we will create a new column name **Leader** which will contain all hierarchy of Manager.

Required Output:

```
| Employee ID | Manager ID  | Leader ID |
|-------------|-------------|-----------|
| E068        | E067        | E001      |
| E071        | E067        | E001      |
| E229        | E069        | E001      |
| E248        | E144        | E001      |
| E226        | E223        | E001      |
| E236        | E241        | E241      |
| E066        | E001        | E001      |
| E067        | E001        | E001      |
| E144        | E001        | E001      |
| E223        | E001        | E001      |
```

The Employee ID column contain UNIQUE ID while Manager ID contain DUPLICATES ID.

Comment: In your example, obviously data is ot fully complete. But just to confirm, take E241 and E001 as example, they have entries in manager_id column, but have no entry of themselves in employee_id columns.
This makes it a lot more complex, if they have their entries in employeed_id column as well with corresponding manager_id null, that would be much easier to solve, and we would not even need leaders table separately, any employee without a manager can be considered a leader. Of-course this might not be your buiseness rule, but want to confirm these scenarios. Please update question and tag me

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal Thanks I have just updated my question by adding E001 and E241 Null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a canonical example of [WITH RECURSIVE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

> Using RECURSIVE, a WITH query can refer to its own output.

Try this:

```
with recursive subordinates as
  (select 
      employeid, 
      e.managerid, 
      e.managerid as leader 
   from employes e 
   where e.managerid in(select * from leaders) -- non recursive term
   union 
   select 
      e.employeid, 
      e.managerid, 
      a.managerid as leader 
    from employes e 
          join subordinates a on a.employeid = e.managerid -- recursive term
) select * from subordinates
```

As described in documentation:

A *WITH RECURSCIVE* is always composed by

1. A non recursive term
2. *UNION* or *UNION ALL*
3. A recursive term, **the only one which can refer to the query output**

The recusion teminates when the previous iteration has no output.

Comment: After some modification my query returns this error  ERROR: each UNION query must have the same number of columns

Comment: My code is ````with recursive subordinates as (select *  from data e  where e.manager in( 'E001', 'E241')union select * from data e join subordinates a on a.emp_id = e.manager) select * from subordinates ````

Comment: In the recursive term, replace `select * ` with `select e.* `